# TensorFlow unable to load image files from filepath

Tags: file, tensorflow, path, google-colaboratory

I am currently doing a lab on Transfer Learning and we use TensorFlow in class. I am using the cats and dogs images to experiment with Transfer Learning concepts.

Before the transfer learning stage, I need to load images of the cats and dogs from the file I have unzipped. I have written the following code to load the images from this unzipped file in Google Colab:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
fname = '/Users/xx/documents/yy/dogs-vs-cats/train'
img = image.load_img(fname, target_size=(150, 150))
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
No such file or directory: '/Users/xx/documents/yy/dogs-vs-cats/train'
```

The dogs-vs-cats file is in my documents folder so I'm unsure why this error shows up.

Comment: As the error shows you are passing the wrong path to read the figure.

Comment: The dogs-vs-cats file is stored in my documents folder though

Comment: If it is in document folder then it should be only '/Users/xx/documents/

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on mac system, just go to the folder by using the terminal and then type `pwd` for the correct path and copy it and paste here. I think passing path wont directly read the images. The following link might help you:
https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6

Comment: I pasted in the file path by doing a PWD itself. It did not work even after that

Comment: OP has clarified that they work on Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is in your documents folder, and I think you use Mac as Operating system.

So just try this:

```
fname = '/Users/xx/Documents/yy/dogs-vs-cats/train'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
fname = '/Users/xx/documents/yy/dogs-vs-cats/train'
for imagePath in os.listdir(fname):
        # imagePath contains name of the image for eg. 46214.png 
        inputPath = os.path.join(inPath, imagePath)
        # inputPath will give you '/Users/xx/documents/yy/dogs-vs-cats/train/46214.png'
        img = image.load_img(inputPath, target_size=(150, 150))
```